# How to Enable Full Logging in Balance Transfer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to enable peer/orderer logging in the [Balance Transfer](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/balance-transfer) sample of Hyperledger Fabric, so I can understand the step-by-step consensus and transaction process of my Hyperledger Fabric project.

### ---------

If we start the blockchain network of [chaincode-docker-devmode](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/chaincode-docker-devmode), and go to the **Terminal 1** where this command below is executed

> docker-compose -f docker-compose-simple.yaml up

We can easily see all the peer/orderers/cli logs in the terminal, for example like this:

```
peer         | 2018-07-26 08:58:07.426 UTC [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 73d Entry
peer         | 2018-07-26 08:58:07.426 UTC [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 73e chaincode canonical name: escc:1.1.0
orderer      | 2018-07-26 08:58:07.434 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 3c4 Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Orderer/SampleOrg/Writers
orderer      | 2018-07-26 08:58:07.434 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 3c5 == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Orderer/SampleOrg/Writers
orderer      | 2018-07-26 08:58:07.434 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 3c6 Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
peer         | 2018-07-26 08:58:07.426 UTC [chaincode] sendExecuteMessage -> DEBU 73f [82a18317]Inside sendExecuteMessage. Message TRANSACTION
peer         | 2018-07-26 08:58:07.426 UTC [chaincode] setChaincodeProposal -> DEBU 740 Setting chaincode proposal context...
orderer      | 2018-07-26 08:58:07.435 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 3c7 == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
orderer      | 2018-07-26 08:58:07.435 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 3c8 Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Writers
orderer      | 2018-07-26 08:58:07.435 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 3c9 == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Writers
orderer      | 2018-07-26 08:58:07.436 UTC [orderer/common/blockcutter] Ordered -> DEBU 3ca Enqueuing message into batch
orderer      | 2018-07-26 08:58:07.436 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> DEBU 3cb [channel: myc] Broadcast has successfully enqueued message of type ENDORSER_TRANSACTION from 172.23.0.5:57804
peer         | 2018-07-26 08:58:07.426 UTC [chaincode] setChaincodeProposal -> DEBU 741 Proposal different from nil. Creating chaincode proposal context...
```

In my case, I want to replicate that condition into the Balance Transfer sample. So when I run ./runApp.sh, it will show all the logs.

How can I do that? What environment should I put in Balance Transfer's docker-compose.yaml file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In balance transfer go to directory artifacts and type this command.
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml logs -f` for live logging.[1][2]
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml` logs` for upto the point logs with no live logging.

**NOTE** : When you run the script in balance-transfer, docker starts the docker containers in detached mode : Run containers in the background,print new container names. That's the reason logs are not shown as soon as containers are orchestrated.[3][4]

**References** :
[1] : Docker - How do I view real time logging of Docker containers? (https://success.docker.com/article/view-realtime-container-logging)
[2] : docker container logs | Docker Documentation (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_logs/)
[3] : docker run | Docker Documentation (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)
[4] : docker-compose up | Docker Documentation (https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)